# Checkboxes MVC - Groups - Users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have database with table Users and Roles and I need view that shows me All roles available and checked the ones the user have. I already have method that shows me all roles available and method that shows me the ones user have, but I dont really know how to implement that in view, how to make those checkboxes actually checked. Thanks very much for help

Table roles

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Method for all roles available

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Method for selected roles

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Model

```
public class UserRoleModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }     
    public int? UserID { get; set; }
    public UserRoleModel()
    {
        ListRole = new List<RoleVM>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<RoleVM> ListRole { get; set; }
    public List<RoleVM> UserRole { get; set; }
}

public class RoleVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

View with checkboxes

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListRole.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListRole[i].ID)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected, new { @checked = "checked" }); 
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected, Model.ListRole[i].Name)
}
```

Comment: its not, now I need help with view, previously I needed help with controller.

Comment: If an answer was helpful last time tho, you can mark as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check your list on View:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.ListRole.Count; i++)
{
    if(Model.UserRole.Select(x => x.Name).Contains(Model.ListRole[i].Name))
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListRole[i].ID)
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected, new { @checked = "checked" }); 
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected, Model.ListRole[i].Name)
    }
    else
    {
       @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListRole[i].ID)
       @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected); 
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ListRole[i].IsSelected, Model.ListRole[i].Name)
    }
}
```

Can't say that it's best way, but it will work. Another aportunity is to fill your model `IsSelected` field right.

Comment: still unchecked :/ and when I change if(Model.UserRole.Contains(Model.ListRole[i])) to if(Model.UserRole.Contains(Model.UserRole[i])) it gives me exeption, in other way it just skips the if codes

Comment: I have just found out that IsSelected is always false, damn

Comment: @shad0wec that's what i was talking about =) If you fill it right - you don't need any conditions and `htmlAttributes`

Answer (score 0):

In MVC and Razor checkboxes are checked when they have a value, so basically you have to attach correct value to the ones which are checked.

As per documentation:

```
public static MvcHtmlString CheckBoxFor<TModel>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> expression
)
```

take into consideration that `expression` is not a checkbox value but rather model binding, so I'd suggest using:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ListRole[i]);
```

Where `m.ListRole[i]` represents some boolean value in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MVCCheckboxList? If you can use this library, would look something like this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxListFor(m => //string array that is bound to your model, will have selected options on POST
    m => //SelectList of all available items
    m => m.Value,
    m => m.Text,
    m => //collection of SelectListItem for all selected items,
    MvcCheckBoxList.Model.Position.Vertical,
    x => new { @class = "editor-cbl" })
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you database structure is incorrect as I have noted in your previous questions. To correctly represent this your need 3 tables, `Users`, `Roles` and `UserRoles` which is a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Roles` and contains fields for `UserID`(FK to `Users` table) and `RoleID` (FK to `Roles` table).

You have indicated your not prepared to change this (meaning you can never even add a new role, can't change the name of existing roles etc. etc.) but at the very least you need some representation of all available roles. Querying existing roles using `Distinct()` cannot work since initially the database will be empty. And your model does not need 2 collections of `RoleVM` (your only editing one).

You need to start by creating a collection of `RoleVM` based on all roles, and then set the `IsSelected` property based on the current roles for the user.

Your GET method needs to be something like

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
  // Get all roles
  IEnumerable<string> roles = new List<string>(){ "Administrator", "Gestor", "Supervisor", "SecurityManager", "Admin" };
  // Get the User
  User user = db.Users().Where(u => u.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
  // Get the user roles (if not included in User model
  IEnumerable<UserRole> userRoles = db.UserRoles().Where(r => r.UserID == ID);
  // Create collection of all roles
  List<RoleVM> allRoles = roles.Select(r => new RoleVM()
  {
    Name = r
  }).ToList();

  // Set the ID and IsSelected properties based on the user roles
  foreach(RoleVM role in allRoles)
  {
    UserRole userRole = userRoles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Role == role.Name);
    if (userRole != null)
    {
      role.ID = userRole.ID;
      role.IsSelected = true;
    }
  }

  // Initialize the view model
  UserVM model = new UserVM()
  {
    ID = user.ID,
    Name = user.Name,
    Roles = allRoles
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

and in the view, remove the `new { @checked = "checked" }` from the `CheckBoxFor()` method